# ubuntu 13.4 not booting up/ will installing ubuntu from usb erase what i have

Tags: 13.04, updates

Yesterday i was going to update my 13.4 to 13.10 by terminal.But whenever i try to set my brightness my netbook freezes for a bit and then it gets going normally.During the update it froze and i thought it would get going normally for a bit so i went to sleep but when i awoke it was still frozen. i turned it off and on and when it says ubuntu then it loads it just takes me to black screen with a " _ " flashing.

I have a bootable ubuntu 13.10 usb which i tried and it worked. so my question is will i have to install ubuntu again and will it erase all my other stuff and could i fix the flashing _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> During the update it froze froze and i thought it would get going normally for a bit so > i went to sleep but when i awoke it was still frozen. i turned it off and on and when it > says ubuntu then it loads it just takes me to black screen with a " _ " flashing.

That's not good, not good at all. The good news is that the kernel isn't panicking which means that you could probably fix this issue with enough work. The bad news is I have no idea what is broken. It could be an easy fix or it could be a multi hour long slug fest and still not have a working computer.

> I have a bootable ubuntu 13.10 usb which i tried and it worked. so my
>   question is will i have to install ubuntu again and will it erase all
>   my other stuff and could i fix the flashing _

If you install from the usb key it will delete your stuff from your previous install. If you have back ups of your files and don't have anything you need on your computer you can just do a fresh install of 13.10 and get back to a working computer. Otherwise you can either try fixing your problem or just recovering the files on your computer.

I would recommend just installing 13.10 if you were planning on upgrading to it anyways. It sounds like you are not an technical savvy user and trying to fix your old install will just lead to head-aches.